# What to use for error bars?

Tags: confidence-interval, interpretation, standard-deviation, standard-error

When shall we use one standard deviation/error as opposed to a specified number of it, therefore producing a particular confidence interval?

And what would be the interpretation of these 2 different methods, i.e. significance for a difference, significance for a coefficient, etc?

Comment: There are many different things that error bars can represent.  Probably the most useful are standard error of the mean and 95% confidence interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, under the assumption of approximate normality there are certain well-defined regions based on standard deviation which have a fixed probability derived from the standard normal distribution: 
1) Mean plus/minus 1 standard deviation contains approximately 67% of the normally distributed data. 
2) Mean plus/minus 1.96 standard deviation contains exactly 95% of the normally distributed data which is the relation where the heuristic confidence region mean plus/minus 2 standard deviations comes from. 
3) Finally, mean plus/minus 3 standard deviations contains approximately 99.7% of the normally distributed data.

So to come back to you question regarding interpretation, the location estimator plus/minus standard error, scenario 1), represents the "center of the data or area you expect to cover the value of your estimator".
Scenario 2) is typically used as the 95%  confidence interval for estimators. 
Scenario 3) can be used for outlier detection under approximate normality, as 3 out of 1000 points are to lie outside this interval.

Comment: As far as I understand this answer, it would be confusing to the reader, because you are conflating standard deviation in the first paragraph with standard error of the mean in the second paragraph. On a normal distribution, the mean plus or minus 1.96 standard deviations contains 95% of the data. But the 95% confidence interval is something different. For the mean, it can be calculated as 1.96 times the standard error of the mean. Perhaps this is what your answer intends, but I find it likely to confuse the reader.